# How to hide lines on LineChart?

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there any way to hide lines on plot? I tried:

```
renderer.setLineWidth(0f);
```

and

```
renderer.setPointStrokeWidth(0f);
```

but no luck.

I'm using achartengine-1.1.0 [[link](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/detail?name=achartengine-1.1.0.jar&can=2&q=)]

Comment: In your question you should specify which library you are using and if this is web based. Also, it should say in the achartengine documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Just used Scatter Plot..

Changed from:

```
    GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);
```

to

```
        GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getScatterChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);
```

facepalm